# Removing queryset from ManyToMany relationship in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I have models Amenity and Property shown below

```
class Amenity(models.Model):
     feature= models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name='feature')


class Property(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length = 500,verbose_name='Property name')
     amenities = models.ManyToManyField(Amenity, null=True, blank=True)
```

How I remove queryset relationship without affecting the related models?

How remove relation of all amenities of property object without deleting amenity objects?

I tried

```
for a in property.amenities.all():
   property.amenities.remove(a)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you wish to remove the dependency (m-m relationship) from the database or just from django models ? Are you using syncdb or south to populate the db ?

Comment: I want remove dependency from database

Answer (score 0):

`property.amenties.clear()` is what you want.

see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/